# How to specify replacment range in excel if formula

Tags: excel

Hi  I am trying to use a formula to change the values of the next rows if a condition is true. I would like this to be based on the time but for now i am trying to just use a range.

I am not sure why it is putting a 0 instead of replacing the range with a 1.Here is my formula

```
=IF(C7=1,B7:B16=1,"K")
```

***Example:***
[image]

I would like it to work like this

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAf5c.png)

Comment: I'm assuming you're putting a formula in a cell. A formula in a cell assigns a value to that cell. As far as I know you can't use it to modify another cell. So you'd have to put your formula in B7 to B16. If($C$7=1,1,"k"). Alternatively you could write a small macro if it's important not to have the formulas in B7 to B16.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes I have formulas in the cells basically I am trying to find the last 1's in the column and then in a separate column change the next few cells to 1.see the desired out put picture. I started in row E as my data.The formula in column D is =IF(E1=1,AND(IF(E2=0,1,0)),0). Column C has INT to turn true into 1. Row B just gives me the 1 value of the condition I am looking for. I am not to good at macros but i think that might be the only way to do what i am trying.

Comment: I'm sorry, you've kind of lost me. What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you need all those columns or are you only after 1 column and the others are helper columns? You say you want it to work on date.What do you want to do with the dates? Maybe that'd be easier. Your expected results are had to use without knowing what each column 1/0/TRUE/FALSE means.

Comment: They are helper columns.The time idea would work as a timing filter. If the cell is the last number 1 in the group of 1s in column E then filter the next 2 minuets. For example,  in the picture above E2 is the last 1 in the group. so I am trying to put a 1 from the time 0:02-0:04.

Comment: Since  2 minuets would be 2 cells I was thinking it would be easier to make a formula for the range instead of the time.